# Change the language of the A-Z catalog

Tags: language-setting

When I'm viewing a list of things and they are grouped by letter, I can click the letter and a picker like this pops up:
[image]
The last element ("international" - the globe icon) shows the entries in other languages. Can I change the language of the "primary" catalog? I want to get a map of the letters in my native language and have the rest under "international" (English included). Perfectly I need this only in my Peope app.

I've tried changing the language of the phone to my language, and it has the desired effect, but I prefer to keep English as my main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the user interface language is an all-or-nothing thing.  The only way you could change this *just for the people app* would be to redesign the app to allow specifying the langauge *for that app*.

Comment: Thanks. Expected this kind of answer, but was hoping for something else.